# Numpy: stack duplicates of matrix in new dimension

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have a 3x3 numpy array and I want to create a 3x3xC matrix where the new dimension consists of exact copies of the original 3x3 array. I am sure this is asked somewhere but I couldn't find the best way. I worked out how to do this for a simple 1 dimensional array x:

```
new_x = np.tile(np.array(x, (C, 1))
```

which repeats the array, then do:

```
np.transpose(np.expand_dims(new_x, axis=2),(2,1,0))
```

which expands the dimension and switches the axis so that the array is repeated in the 3rd dimension (although this works I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it either) - what is the most efficient way to do this for a general n x n numpy array?

Comment: Not sure if I understand, but you could do the same thing with `np.tile(x, (C, 1)).T`?

Comment: This will just transpose a 2 dimensional matrix, I want the array to be repeated in the 3rd dimension.

Comment: My favourite solution to that would be broadcasting like so `new_x = np.empty((3, 3, 2), dtype=x.dtype); new_x[...] = x[..., None]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a readonly version, `broadcast_to` can be used:

```
In [370]: x = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
In [371]: x
Out[371]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
In [372]: x = np.broadcast_to(x[..., None],(3,3,10))
In [373]: x
Out[373]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]],

       [[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
        [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]],

       [[6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
        [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7],
        [8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8]]])
```

Or with `repeat`:

```
In [378]: x=np.repeat(x[...,None],10,2)
In [379]: x
Out[379]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]],

       [[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
        [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]],

       [[6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
        [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7],
        [8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8]]])
```

This is a larger array, whose elements can be changed individually.

Comment: Nice. Are `(3, 3, 10)` hardcoded here?

Comment: You could construct the tuple from `x.shape` and `C`.

Comment: Nice one. So `broadcast_to` would be the official version of all that `stride_tricks` black magic?

Comment: new_x = np.repeat(x[...,None],C,2) worked like a charm - excellent. What does the None do in [...,None]? Why is this necessary?

Comment: Here `None` is `np.newaxis`; `np.expand_dims(x,2)` does the same thing, make a (3, 3, 1) array.